# The closure of a connected set is connected.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

This is a proof by contradiction, unsing the definition of connectedness from Rudin, Principles of Mathematical Anaylsis. Can someone please check if it is any good?

Suppose S is a connected set, where its closure $ \bar{S} $ is not connected. Therefore there exist two nonempty sets A and B, such that $ \bar{A} \cap B = \bar{B}  \cap A = \emptyset $ and $ A \cup B = \bar{S}$. Define $ G:= A \cap S $ and $ H:= B \cap S $. Because G is a subset of A and H is a subset of B, it is clear that $ \bar{G} \cap H = \bar{H}  \cap G = \emptyset $. and $A\cup B = S$. So that S is not connected, contrary to our first assumption. q.e.d.

Thank you

Comment: You seem to have changed your $S$ into an $E$ at the end there.

Comment: Thanks. If that is the only mistake I am happy :)

Comment: $G$ and $H$ are the same set. This is probably not what you want.

Comment: Shouldn't $A\cap\overline{S}$ and $B\cap\overline{S}$ be assumed to be nonempty, for the contradiction?

Comment: thanks again. Is the reasoning being clear, though?

Comment: Something is not quite right. You have not used the assumption that $\overline{S}$ is not connected.

Comment: I think you want to say: There exist subsets $A$ and $B$ such that $\overline{S} = A\cup B$ and $A\cap\overline{B} = \overline{A}\cap B =\varnothing$.

Comment: The current version is correct.

Comment: I am having trouble seeing why $A \cup B \subset S$ follows.

Answer (score 3):

The contradiction is that $G\cup H = S$ where G and H are separated, not $A\cup B=S$

Comment: Can you be sure that $G$ and $H$ are both not empty?

Comment: Yes, if $x \in S$ then $x \in \overline{S}$, and then $x \in A $ or $x \in B$. If $x \in A$ then $x \in A \cap S$, which implies that $A \cap S \neq \emptyset$. Now, since $A \cup B = \overline{S}$ with $A \cap B = \emptyset$, then $B = \overline{S} - A$. $B \cap S =  (\overline{S} - A) \cap S = \overline{S} \cap A^{c} \cap S = S - A = \emptyset$ if and only if $S = A$, but $\overline{A} \cap B = \overline{S} \cap B = \emptyset$, which implies that $B = \emptyset$ due to $B \subset \overline{S}$, but $B$ is a non emptyset by definition, which is a contradiction. So, $B \cap S \neq 0$ too.

Comment: That works well, thank you. Another proof, organized slightly differently, is the one I wrote here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4122663/688046